# Proof of the denumerability of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know I could just look this up, but I thought I'd just ask because I like this site and I get feedback.

To prove a set is denumerable we have to show there exists a bijection from the set in question.  So to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is denumerable, we just need a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$.

I thought of such a bijection, namely, $f(n)=(-1)^{n}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$.

This seems to do the trick but I'm feeling like there are simpler mappings that I'm not seeing.

Comment: That's the one I would choose.

Comment: There are no simpler ones?  How about slightly more complex?

Comment: I would probably choose to *express* it differently, by using cases rather than the floor function. But it would be essentially the same.

Comment: can I ask why?  wouldn't the floor sort of compactify notation?

Comment: It does, but often clarity is favored over compactness.

Comment: what would be the best way by cases?

Comment: No best way. Maybe let $f(1)=0$. For $n\gt 1$, let  $f(n)=n/2$ if $n$ is even, and let $f(n)=-(n-1)/2$ if $n$ is odd. Note that we could have dispensed with the case $n=1$, but didn't.

Answer (score 1):

How about the piecewise defined function which assigns $0$ to $0$, each positive even number $2n$ to $n$ and each positive odd $2n-1$ to $-n$?

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, but that to me seems like too many assignments.  but it is cleaner, i must say.

Comment: This is almost exactly what Iceman's function does.

Comment: I agree. Just a different way to write it

Answer (score 0):

First, let's recall that $\mathbb{Z}$ can be defined in the following terms (it's not the only way to construct the set of the integers, but this construction is good enough for our purposes)

Let

$$\mathcal{Z}=2\times\mathbb{N}$$

And let

$$\mathbb{Z}=\mathcal{Z}/\sim$$

Where $\sim$ is the relation that identifies $\langle 0,0\rangle$ with $\langle 1,0\rangle$ (leaving the remaining elements of $\mathcal{Z}$ untouched), and call this element *the zero element of*$\;\mathbb{Z}$; let's denote it by $0_\mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand, every element with first coordinate equal to $0$ other tan $0_\mathbb{Z}$ will be called a *negative integer number*, while every element with first coordinate equal to $1$ other tan $0_\mathbb{Z}$ will be called a *positive integer number*.

After this digression into the formal construction of $\mathbb{Z}$, we can define the desired surjection.

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be defined by: for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
  0_\mathbb{Z}\qquad\,\text{if }n=0\\
  \langle 0,k\rangle\quad\text{if }n=2k\;\text{for some }k\in\mathbb{N}\\
  \langle 1,k\rangle\quad\text{if }n=2k+1\;\text{for some }k\in\mathbb{N}
\end{cases}$$

It also follows that $f$ is not only surjective, but also injective.

In my opinion, this function is easier to understand and to handle than the one you gave, for reasons of simplicity: you are using powers, rational numbers and the floor function, which are complex objects (from a set-theoretical point of view) to fully describe your function, whereas the function I gave above is elementary and doesn't require anything but the existence of $\mathbb{N}$ and cartesian products.